# Xcode 6.0.1 stuck compiling asset

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, xcode6

I've been trying to compile an iOS 7 project with all the beta versions of Xcode 6 with no luck and I was hoping for the stable version to work but it doesn't. When I try to compile the app it always works fine until it starts compiling the asset catalog. I tried to compile other projects with assets and work fine, and also works for new projects.

Does anyone know what the problem can be? The last line in the build log corresponds to the file assetcatalog_generated_info.plist

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I faced the similar issue and the following fixed for me...
Modify the assetcatalog file and clean(shift+cmd+alt+k) and build.

Answer (score 3):

I did above without success- I ended up just 
1. rebooting my machine
2. Cleaning my build folder - (hold down Alt key and press Product-> Clean )

which did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some image corrupted in your Images.xcassets. I advise you to copy your Images.xcassets for another place, delete it from project, create a new one and go back each image (and compiling) for discovering which one is the problem.